# Call ordering in DWR

Tags: dwr

There is an option to make DWR AJAX calls to execute in sequence thru the following option

```
DWREngine.setOrdered(true)
```

But this is working globally (for entire application).
I want to make enable this option only to certain Classes.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in the following way

```
DWREngine.beginBatch();
BatchCallClass.method1(testCallBatchingCallback1);
BatchCallClass.method2(testCallBatchingCallback2);
MathDelegate.multiply(8, 4, testCallBatchingCallback3);
DWREngine.endBatch();
```

in this way you avoid to change the behaivor of all you entire application.